# Sorting by $natural or _id doesn't provide accurate recent record

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I've stored live session data on a MongoDB instance.  Using mongoose on NodeJS with following queries doesn't provide accurate latest data of a specific user. I always see older record when I execute the following queries but sometimes it gives correct one, and most of times I see older record stacked up as first and the recent one stacked as second or third so on.

```
let UserLayer = await table.find({ ip: ipAddress }).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1).exec();

let UserLayer2 = await table.find({ ip: ipAddress }).sort({$natural : -1}).limit(1).exec();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Natural order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order) does not mean "chronological". If you want chronological ordering, store timestamps in your documents and sort by the timestamps.

Comment: Would you mind to add an example for timestamps if I have to go with timestamps route?

Comment: I used _id too and told by people _id contain timestamps

Comment: _id will contain timestamps if you write timestamps there, otherwise they won't.

Comment: Automatically generated ObjectIds are mostly sequential but are not guaranteed to be, in fact they are guaranteed to NOT be sequential eventually with sufficient write volume.

Comment: I just tried with timestamps. I added timestamp field and stored unix epoch timestamps there and indexed that field. It seems work fine for one collection but the other one return old records instead most recent.

Comment: Update question with reproduce code, actual & expected output.

Comment: Or better yet make a new question.

Comment: I made a new question. Please have a look if you can!